# error installing RFast library due to isnan ambigous

Tags: r, installation

In R,  version 3.6  I am trying to install the Rfast library in a Linux Centos 7 system

By giving the command:

```
install.packages("Rfast")
```

A long list of compilation occurs and at the end it finishes with this message:
[image: compilation error]

Is there a way to get it installation successful ?

Comment: Thus error has been fixed.